# Adding "SelectByRectangle" tool to ArcMap custom toolbar Add-In

Tags: arcmap, add-in, toolbar

I am able to show the other esriArcMapUI selection tools in my custom toolbar, but "Select By Rectangle" does not appear. 
What is the correct Tool refID of it?

```
<ESRI.Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.esri.com/Desktop/AddIns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
 <AddInID>{6fa0df73-57ab-491e-a73d-e58ce07af414}</AddInID>
  <Description>Test custom toolbar.</Description>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <Image>Images\SelectionSample.png</Image>
  <Author>test</Author>
  <Company>ESRI</Company>
  <Date>6/6/2013</Date>
  <Targets>
    <Target name="Desktop" version="10.1" />
  </Targets>
  <AddIn language="CLR" library="SelectionSample.dll" namespace="SelectionSample">
    <ArcMap>
      <Commands>        
        <ToolPalette id="ESRI_SelectionSample_ToolPalette" caption="Selection Palette" isMenuStyle="false" category="Framework AddIn Samples" >
          <Items>
            <Tool refID="esriArcMapUI.SelectByRectangleTool" />  
            <Tool refID="esriArcMapUI.SelectByPolygonTool" />
            <Tool refID="esriArcMapUI.SelectByLassoTool" />
            <Tool refID="esriArcMapUI.SelectByCircleTool" />                
          </Items>
        </ToolPalette>
    </ArcMap>
  </AddIn>
</ESRI.Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`esriArcMapUI.SelectFeaturesTool`

I can't find a way to directly link to it, but if you go here and search by `Select by Rectangle`, you'll see the ProgID:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/0001/00010000029s000000.htm

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I spend hours looking at the esriArcMapUI API with no success. I follow the naming convention of the rest of the selecting tools. I was wrongly looking for "SelectBy...Tool". I guess because this is the default tool it is called just SelectFeaturesTool, instead of SelectByRectangleTool

Answer (score 1):

according to the help,here is your answer

[image: according to the help]